# Converting date and/or time from character string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a view, and a part of the code looks like this:

```
, IIF (ownedbyteamt = 'Validation' 
       AND (titlet LIKE '%Build validation%' 
            OR 
            titlet LIKE '%OP Build%'),
       CAST(closeddatetimet AS NVARCHAR(255)), '-1111111') AS 'OP_Build_Validation'
```

Then, I used this view in a join with the table and the code that I have there looks like this:

```
,( 
CASE 
   WHEN cher.[Max_OP Build Validation] <> -111111 
        AND cher.max_cf <> -111111 
        AND cher.max_cf >= cher.max_op_build _validation 
      THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, cher.max_cf), CONVERT(DATE, cher.max_op_build_validation)) 
      ELSE '07/07/1777' 
END) AS 'Days-Cf'
```

Now, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: A column must have the same type.  In this case, one branch is returning `INT`.  Another is returning a `VARCHAR`.  Make up your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single value with a specified type.

You have a `then` clause that returns a `datediff()`.  That is an integer.

You have an `else` clause that returns a string.

When there are different types, SQL Server uses type conversion rules to figure out what to do.  In this case, it tries to convert everything to an integer -- and you get an error.

Comment: How can I fix it? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @nina_dev No one can suggest any correction because no one knows your schema nor what you are trying to accomplish. Your first mistake was converting closedatetimet to nvarchar and storing a completely bogus value when the logic evaluated to TRUE. That choice now causes the problem you have in your view usage. You need help with your schema first - all that casting of columns between string and date is a sign of significant design problems.

Comment: @nina_dev . . . Ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.